# How to uninstall TeX Live 2019 on Windows 10?

Tags: installing, texlive-2019

Each online installation of TeX Live 2019 is an utter **failure**. In each and every attempt I’m left with an incomplete install. With each subsequent retry the installer warns against [re-]installing in the default directory once files are contained there (from previous installs). Now I’m just furious and I don’t want to have a trace of TeX Live in my computer anymore. Despite the fact the [documentation](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.pdf) claims there is an uninstaller under the Control Panel or the Start menu, this simply isn’t true (I’m on Windows 10). Even if I attempted a lower “scheme” light weight installation at this point, what am I to expect when the default directory is already flooded with files from the previous full installation attempts? Therefore, I just want to get rid of it, but how?

Comment: texlive makes no registry entries so just delete the folder, you need no special uninstall.

Answer (score 21):

goto texlive installation folder (Default install path is **C:\texlive\2019\tlpkg\installer**)
and run **uninst.bat** file

Comment: Where is no uninst.bat

Comment: I checked it in texlive 2022, it still in *Installer* folder
C:\texlive\2022\tlpkg\installer\uninst.bat

Comment: There's also an `uninst2.bat`. Does anyone know what that's for?